# PrimeNG ptable - implement different logic for all the dynamic rows

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm working on a Payment verification functionality in which the user enters the transaction id and a button click checks it.

The table of all the transactions are fetched from an API which then creates multiple rows dynamically using the pTable of Prime NG. The problem is, if i implement a checking logic on any one of the transaction records, all of them are verified.

I need to check each transaction separately.

Here's my component ts file

```
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { AllServicesService } from 'src/app/Services/all-services.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-payment-verification',
  templateUrl: './payment-verification.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./payment-verification.component.scss']
})
export class PaymentVerificationComponent implements OnInit {
  dataSource: any[] = [];
  
  status: any
  data: any
  check: boolean = false;
  input_data:[]
  displayedCols:any[];  
  transactionid:any;
  // @ViewChild('transactionId') transactionId:HTMLementRef;
  selected: any;
  constructor(
    private allService: AllServicesService,
    private frmBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {  this.displayedCols =[
    {field: 'CustID', header:'Customer ID'},
    {field: 'Cust_Name',header:'Name'},
    {field: 'date', header:'Date'},
    {field: 'Amount', header:'Amount'},
    {field: 'BankName',header:'Bank Name'},
    {header:'Transaction ID', field: 'TransactionID', editable:true, state:false},
    // {field: 'status', header:' Status'},
    // {field: 'submit', header: 'Submit'}
  ];}
  
  ngOnInit() {
   
    this.verifytransaction(this.status);
  }
  verify(){
    console.log("clicked")
      this.dataSource.forEach(function(rowData){
        console.log('data: ' + 'UserID:' + rowData.CustID + 'Transaction ID:' + rowData.TransactionID);

      });
    //  this.dataSource.forEach(function(rowData) {
    //     console.log(rowData.TransactionID)
    //  });
    this.check = true;
    }
  verifytransaction(status) {
    this.allService.paymentVerification(status)
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.dataSource = res.data
        this.dataSource.map(res => { res.Amount })
        // console.log(this.dataSource);
      })

  } 
}
```

My component template is as follows:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <p-table [value]="dataSource" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selected" [columns]="displayedCols">
        <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
            <tr>
                <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
                    {{col.header}}
                </th>
                <th>
                    Status
                </th>
                <th>
                    Submit
                </th>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns"  let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
            <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
                <td *ngFor="let col of columns" [pEditableColumn] [ngClass]="{'disable-td' : !col.editable}">
                      <div *ngIf="!col.editable">
                        {{rowData[col.field]}}
                      </div>
                      <p-cellEditor *ngIf="col.editable">
                              <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                                  <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowData[col.field]" #trd required>
                              </ng-template>
                              <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                                  {{rowData[col.field]}}
                              </ng-template>   
                      </p-cellEditor>
                </td>
                <td >
                    <div >
                        <button *ngIf="!check" pButton type="button"  (click)="verify()">Verify</button>
                        <span>
                            <i class="pi pi-check" *ngIf="check"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
        </p-table>
</div>
```

Here's the table that is created when the API returns the data. The TransactionID column is editable:
[image: Table]

on clicking any of the verify buttons, all are marked as verified.
[image: on clicking]

Answer (score 0):

What is triggering the change is the single variable `check` from your component body.

So when you change it once, it applies the change to all rows.

You need to make so there is a `check` variable per data row.

on your subscription, add check:

```
this.allService.paymentVerification(status)
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.dataSource = res.data.map(item => {...item, check: false}) // <== here
        this.dataSource.map(res => { res.Amount })
        // console.log(this.dataSource);
      })
```

and update your "verify" function:

```
verify(rowData){
  rowData.check = true;
}
```

and on your template:

```
<td >
  <div >
    <button *ngIf="!rowData.check" pButton type="button"  (click)="verify(rowData)">Verify</button>
    <span><i class="pi pi-check" *ngIf="rowData.check"></i></span>
 </div>                    
</td>
```

Comment: I understood all the other explanations but the first one is unclear.
I don't understand what exactly I need to implement in the subscription.

Comment: I also need the customer ID and the transaction ID that will be entered in each row on the button click. Tried many methods but none seems to work. Please help.

Comment: you need to modify the data in the table adding a check attribute to the items:  `{...item, check: false}` (line 3 in the fist block) all the attributes from the data are now in the button click, this variable `rowData` I added there , should have them all

Comment: the implementation gives error and still its not working